# Calling stored function in hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have tried multiple ways to call stored function in hibernate---

1) Via Session.doWork callback method

```
session.doWork(new Work() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void execute(Connection conn)
                                                throws SQLException {
                                              CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall("{? = call test(?)}");
                                              stmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
                                              stmt.setString(2, "callIndex");
                                              stmt.execute();
                                              eventVal = stmt.getInt(1);


                                        }
                        });
```

This works fine but cannot return any thing from here, so doesn't solve my purpose.

2) Via Native query

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
query.append("Select test() from dual");
SQLQuery sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(query.toString());
List resultList = sqlQuery.list();
events = new ArrayList<Events>();
Object result = null;
if (events != null && !events.isEmpty()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < events.size(); i++) {
        result = resultList.get(i);
    }
}
```

This doesn't work and gives me some No Dialect mapping for JDBC type -10, not sure of the reason.

3) Via named query

My entity class is ---

```
@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(name = "testCall",
            query = "? = call test()",
                    hints = {@QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.callable", value = "true" )},
           resultClass = Events.class
            )

})
@Entity
@Table(name = "EVENTS")
public class Events implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -24850323296832289L;

    /** The id. */
    @Id
    @Column(name = "EVENT_SID")
    private Integer eventId;

    /** The processed status. */
    @Column(name = "EVENT_STATUS")
    private String eventStatus;

    /** The event type. */
    @Column(name = "EVENT_TYPE_NAME")
    private String eventType;

    /** The live event. */
    @Column(name = "IS_LIVE_EVENT")
    private Integer liveEvent;

    /** The event message. */
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "EVENT_MESSAGE")
    private String eventMessage;

    public Integer getEventId() {
        return eventId;
    }

    public void setEventId(Integer eventId) {
        this.eventId = eventId;
    }

    public String getEventStatus() {
        return eventStatus;
    }

    public void setEventStatus(String eventStatus) {
        this.eventStatus = eventStatus;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the event type.
     * 
     * @return the event type
     */
    public String getEventType() {
        return eventType;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the event type.
     * 
     * @param eventType
     *            the new event type
     */
    public void setEventType(String eventType) {
        this.eventType = eventType;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the live event.
     * 
     * @return the live event
     */
    public Integer getLiveEvent() {
        return liveEvent;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the live event.
     * 
     * @param liveEvent
     *            the new live event
     */
    public void setLiveEvent(Integer liveEvent) {
        this.liveEvent = liveEvent;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the event message.
     * 
     * @return the event message
     */
    public String getEventMessage() {
        return eventMessage;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the event message.
     * 
     * @param eventMessage
     *            the new event message
     */
    public void setEventMessage(String eventMessage) {
        this.eventMessage = eventMessage;
    }

}
```

The DAO through which I am making call have method ---

```
   public Integer callSqlBlock(){
        int event = 0;
        Session session = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        List<Events> events = null;
        events = session.getNamedQuery("testCall").list();
        return events.get(0).getEventId();
    }
```

stored function on the DB end ---

```
create or replace 
function            test return SYS_REFCURSOR
as
p_order_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
begin
open p_order_recordset FOR SELECT EVENT_SID,EVENT_STATUS,EVENT_TYPE_NAME,IS_LIVE_EVENT FROM events;
return p_order_recordset;
end ;
```

execution of stored function via named query is giving me invalid column index

Please let me know where I am going wrong on this, and if possible please provide some example also

Comment: Whats the exception you are getting ?. What does your procedure look like ?

Comment: Arun, please see the edited question, been more elaborated now